# Wi-Fi connection mysteriously doesn't work with some routers

Tags: debian, networking, connman

I run Debian 11 with the LXQt desktop environment. I have noted that Wi-Fi works with some routers but not with others. I also have the same software setup on a different computer and it has the same problem with the same routers. My conclusion is that it must be related to connman which is the default network manager in LXQt.

The two routers I'm having problem with is an Apple Airport Express and my iPhone (used as personal hotspot). In the Connman window it says that I'm connected but still I have no internet access (see pictures below). I have also tried the command line:

```
$ connmanctl
Error getting VPN connections: The name net.connman.vpn was not provided by any .sconnmanctl> agent on
Agent registered
connmanctl> scan wifi
Scan completed for wifi
connmanctl> services
[snip]
*Ac iPhone               wifi_d03c1f255599_6950686f6e65_managed_psk
[snip]
connmanctl> connect wifi_d03c1f255599_6950686f6e65_managed_psk
Connected wifi_d03c1f255599_6950686f6e65_managed_psk
connmanctl> quit
$ ping www.google.com
ping: www.google.com: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

How can I troubleshoot the issue? What should I check next?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the issue is caused by the DNS servers from my internet service provider not accepting traffic from outside the network. What my two computers have in common is that they were both using my router at home when I installed Debian so the ISP's DNS servers were added to /etc/resolv.conf.

After changing DNS servers to Google's public DNS and restarting the computer it all works as expected:

```
$ sudo sh
# cat > /etc/resolv.conf
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4       
# chattr i+ /etc/resolv.conf
# systemctl reboot
```